# Assigning GridTable to a wx.Grid overrides all wxFormBuilder settings

Tags: wxpython, wxformbuilder

Using the wxFormBuilder, I set all kind of layout properties on my wxGrid.
However, when in code I assign a table to the grid `grid.SetTable(table)` these properties seem to be overriden by other (default? from table?) behaviour.

As an example, column labels, columns sizes, expanding style. All these things set in wxFormBuilder have no effect after setting the table as data source.

How can I make use of a wx.grid.GridTableBase and still benefit from the wxFormBuilder functionality to design my user interface?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: @HudsonMC Sorry, no solution found. This is one of the reasons I am moving away from wxPython.